# How to locate this element? Tried using all kinds of waits, thread sleeps but the element refuses to be located

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

This is from a SAPUI. I have attempted all kinds of XPaths on this element. I have tried them out on the Chrome console too verifying the XPaths are right. I have even tried using JavaScriptExecutor Actions everything else, but it fails to click on it each and every time.

See below code. I want to click on Quotes.

Some of the XPaths I have used:

```
//a[@id="navigationitemNAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c_4475"]

//a[contains(text(), "Quotes")]

//div[@role='Main']//li[@class='sapUiUx3NavBarItemSel']/a[contains(text(), 'Quotes')]
```

Every one of them returns this unable to locate element.

PS: I am sorry I don't know how to copy paste the code here. It comes as one single line of code when I use the 4 space trick.

HTML Code added:

```
<nav id="__bar16" data-sap-ui="__bar16" data-sap-ui-fastnavgroup="true" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-containerid="gTMZ5G7rXqQM1RsPGdQWHW" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" class="sapUiUx3NavBar sapUiUx3NavBarUpperCaseText sapUiUx3NavBarScrollForward" role="navigation" tabindex="0">
 <ul id="__bar16-list" role="menubar" class="sapUiUx3NavBarList" style="white-space:nowrap">
    <li style="display:inline-block"><a id="__bar16-dummyItem" class="sapUiUx3NavBarDummyItem sapUiUx3NavBarItem">&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li style="display:inline-block"><a id="navigationitemCcuq0IkG74_K2rh3LWQ_s4W_4473" data-sap-ui="navigationitemCcuq0IkG74_K2rh3LWQ_s4W_4473" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-modelid="Ccuq0IkG74_K2rh3LWQ$4W" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" data-sap-automation-id="Ccuq0IkG74_K2rh3LWQ$4W" href="#" aria-setsize="18" aria-posinset="1" role="menuitemradio" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" aria-checked="false">Overview</a></li>
    <li style="display:inline-block"><a id="navigationitemNCkvR0ZHXKgmQFks1tvHvG_4474" data-sap-ui="navigationitemNCkvR0ZHXKgmQFks1tvHvG_4474" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-modelid="NCkvR0ZHXKgmQFks1tvHvG" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" data-sap-automation-id="NCkvR0ZHXKgmQFks1tvHvG" href="#" aria-setsize="18" aria-posinset="2" role="menuitemradio" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" aria-checked="false">Products</a></li>
    <li style="display:inline-block" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItemSel"><a id="navigationitemNAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c_4475" data-sap-ui="navigationitemNAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c_4475" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-modelid="NAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" data-sap-automation-id="NAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c" href="#" aria-setsize="18" aria-posinset="3" role="menuitemradio" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" tabindex="-1" aria-checked="true">Quotes</a></li>
    <li style="display:inline-block"><a id="navigationitemHnYQXmNzpKsQ_svo9v_7Ucm_4476" data-sap-ui="navigationitemHnYQXmNzpKsQ_svo9v_7Ucm_4476" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-modelid="HnYQXmNzpKsQ$vo9v_7Ucm" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" data-sap-automation-id="HnYQXmNzpKsQ$vo9v_7Ucm" href="#" aria-setsize="18" aria-posinset="4" role="menuitemradio" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" aria-checked="false">Feed</a></li>
    <li style="display:inline-block"><a id="navigationitemAPb3M2Dc14oYbC9UnR2nmW_4479" data-sap-ui="navigationitemAPb3M2Dc14oYbC9UnR2nmW_4479" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-modelid="APb3M2Dc14oYbC9UnR2nmW" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" data-sap-automation-id="APb3M2Dc14oYbC9UnR2nmW" href="#" aria-setsize="18" aria-posinset="6" role="menuitemradio" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" aria-checked="false">Sales Activities</a></li>
    <li style="display:inline-block"><a id="navigationitem3c4XOx_s7j42mfRqSwAA2eW_4480" data-sap-ui="navigationitem3c4XOx_s7j42mfRqSwAA2eW_4480" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-modelid="3c4XOx$7j42mfRqSwAA2eW" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" data-sap-automation-id="3c4XOx$7j42mfRqSwAA2eW" href="#" aria-setsize="18" aria-posinset="7" role="menuitemradio" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" aria-checked="false">Competitors</a></li>
    <li style="display:inline-block"><a id="navigationitembnmA5f4XVK_1waGBR_2Bc0_4481" data-sap-ui="navigationitembnmA5f4XVK_1waGBR_2Bc0_4481" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-modelid="bnmA5f4XVK_1waGBR_2Bc0" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" data-sap-automation-id="bnmA5f4XVK_1waGBR_2Bc0" href="#" aria-setsize="18" aria-posinset="8" role="menuitemradio" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" aria-checked="false">Sales Team</a></li>
    <li style="display:inline-block"><a id="navigationitemFWZk1s_sFJKoD2aGe6F_saYW_4482" data-sap-ui="navigationitemFWZk1s_sFJKoD2aGe6F_saYW_4482" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-modelid="FWZk1s$FJKoD2aGe6F$aYW" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" data-sap-automation-id="FWZk1s$FJKoD2aGe6F$aYW" href="#" aria-setsize="18" aria-posinset="9" role="menuitemradio" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" aria-checked="false">Contacts</a></li>
    <li style="display:inline-block"><a id="navigationitem4jNgg9kvhKQGhD3t9kmXjm_4484" data-sap-ui="navigationitem4jNgg9kvhKQGhD3t9kmXjm_4484" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-modelid="4jNgg9kvhKQGhD3t9kmXjm" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" data-sap-automation-id="4jNgg9kvhKQGhD3t9kmXjm" href="#" aria-setsize="18" aria-posinset="10" role="menuitemradio" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" aria-checked="false">Involved Parties</a></li>
    <li style="display:inline-block"><a id="navigationitemw0SBWQJSI4cZoAZhFWnLsG_4488" data-sap-ui="navigationitemw0SBWQJSI4cZoAZhFWnLsG_4488" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-modelid="w0SBWQJSI4cZoAZhFWnLsG" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" data-sap-automation-id="w0SBWQJSI4cZoAZhFWnLsG" href="#" aria-setsize="18" aria-posinset="12" role="menuitemradio" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" aria-checked="false">Timeline</a></li>
    <li style="display:inline-block"><a id="navigationitemgJDHYohCDKEfyrkvqRzy7m_4489" data-sap-ui="navigationitemgJDHYohCDKEfyrkvqRzy7m_4489" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-modelid="gJDHYohCDKEfyrkvqRzy7m" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" data-sap-automation-id="gJDHYohCDKEfyrkvqRzy7m" href="#" aria-setsize="18" aria-posinset="13" role="menuitemradio" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" aria-checked="false">Document Flow</a></li>
    <li style="display:inline-block"><a id="navigationitemj1QuCToZNK6RuFGhGMCOvG_4492" data-sap-ui="navigationitemj1QuCToZNK6RuFGhGMCOvG_4492" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-modelid="j1QuCToZNK6RuFGhGMCOvG" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" data-sap-automation-id="j1QuCToZNK6RuFGhGMCOvG" href="#" aria-setsize="18" aria-posinset="14" role="menuitemradio" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" aria-checked="false">Attachments</a></li>
    <li style="display:inline-block"><a id="navigationitem0OeJe07pn4ACaAbX_s11Pz0_4497" data-sap-ui="navigationitem0OeJe07pn4ACaAbX_s11Pz0_4497" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-modelid="0OeJe07pn4ACaAbX$11Pz0" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" data-sap-automation-id="0OeJe07pn4ACaAbX$11Pz0" href="#" aria-setsize="18" aria-posinset="15" role="menuitemradio" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" aria-checked="false">Changes</a></li>
    <li style="display:inline-block"><a id="navigationitemNAVIGATIONITEMID_ea96ffcf719448e09193dab60180ef70_4500" data-sap-ui="navigationitemNAVIGATIONITEMID_ea96ffcf719448e09193dab60180ef70_4500" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-modelid="NAVIGATIONITEMID_ea96ffcf719448e09193dab60180ef70" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" data-sap-automation-id="NAVIGATIONITEMID_ea96ffcf719448e09193dab60180ef70" href="#" aria-setsize="18" aria-posinset="16" role="menuitemradio" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" aria-checked="false">Governance</a></li>
    <li style="display:inline-block"><a id="navigationitem59721243ab594d8d89cf28be315a1e98_4501" data-sap-ui="navigationitem59721243ab594d8d89cf28be315a1e98_4501" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-modelid="59721243ab594d8d89cf28be315a1e98" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" data-sap-automation-id="59721243ab594d8d89cf28be315a1e98" href="#" aria-setsize="18" aria-posinset="17" role="menuitemradio" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" aria-checked="false">OPPORTUNITY PLANNING</a></li>
    <li style="display:inline-block"><a id="navigationitem191194b28e914b10ad51961c568fbf2d_4502" data-sap-ui="navigationitem191194b28e914b10ad51961c568fbf2d_4502" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-modelid="191194b28e914b10ad51961c568fbf2d" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" data-sap-automation-id="191194b28e914b10ad51961c568fbf2d" href="#" aria-setsize="18" aria-posinset="18" role="menuitemradio" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" aria-checked="false">PLANNING REPORTS</a></li><span id="__bar16-arrow" style="left: 290px;" class="sapUiUx3NavBarArrow"></span></ul>
<a id="__bar16-ofb" role="presentation" class="sapUiUx3NavBarBack" href="#"></a>
<a id="__bar16-off" role="presentation" class="sapUiUx3NavBarForward" href="#"></a><a id="__bar16-ofl" role="presentation" class="sapUiUx3NavBarOverflowBtn" href="#"><span class="sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" style="font-family: SAP-icons;" data-sap-ui-icon-content="" role="presentation" title="More" id="__bar16-oflt" aria-label="More"></span></a></nav>
```

This is the highlight from there:

```
<a id="navigationitemNAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c_4475" data-sap-ui="navigationitemNAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c_4475" data-flex-dragtype="FacetTab" data-flex-modelid="NAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c" data-flex-component="/BYD_COD/SalesOnDemand/Opportunity/UI/COD_Opportunity_TI.TI.uicomponent&amp;null" data-sap-automation-id="NAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c" href="#" aria-setsize="18" aria-posinset="3" role="menuitemradio" class="sapUiUx3NavBarItem" tabindex="-1" aria-checked="true">Quotes</a>
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Your XPath statements look correct. The issue is likely either that the HTML elements are bound to a namespace, or that the HTML is dynamically being enhanced and adjusted with JavaScript as the page loads/renders. If you could provide a link to an example page, or post some of the actual HTML it would be easier to diagnose.

Comment: One line of code would be  better than a screenshot. Someone could help format and edit. However, you could always format the HTML in a site like http://htmlformatter.com/ and then paste and highlight, and then click the code sample button (`{}`) in the toolbar to indent all of the highlighted lines.

Comment: I notice that this is a navigation menu.  is it always visible, or do you have to take some action to make it visible?  If action is required, are you sure that your code has done that first?

Comment: I have added the HTML code.

I have added couple of waits:

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));

Comment: I click on a button in the page which takes me to another page where I have to click on Quotes. Yes, I reach that page just fine. It's the element which doesn't get clicked on that page.

Answer (score 1):

When the locator is correct then it must be a matter of timing. Try it with an explicit wait like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
WebElement element = wait.until(
                    ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("navigationitemNAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c_4518")));
```

I suppose you checked your locators by using for instance Chrome Developer Tool. See: http://yizeng.me/2014/03/23/evaluate-and-validate-xpath-css-selectors-in-chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: Yup I did use my xpath after verifying in the chrome developer tool. And I had also used the explicit wait earlier without any positive result.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML elements are bound to the HTML namespace, then your XPaths won't match. You could try using a more generic element match, using `*`. Since `@id` are supposed to be unique, the following should be sufficient:

```
//*[@id='navigationitemNAVIGATIONITEMID_7bc2f6d569b74f2fa33d38fa9962135c_4518']
```

For the more generic criteria looking for elements with text that contains the word "Quotes", you might also restrict to match the element's `local-name()`:

```
//*[local-name()='a' and contains(text(),'Quotes')]
```

Comment: I used your second xpath and the output did not say it could not locate the element but it also did not go to the intended page which should come up on clicking "Quotes".

Answer (score 0):

There could be two cases in your scenario which might refuse you to locate..

1. It might be `dynamic id` which changes on each page load.
2. Element might be inside iframe.

As you mentioned earlier in question you have tried all things...It seems element is inside iframe. If this is the case use following way to locate it..

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframe id");
```